# How simulate insufficient_funds with the stripe terminal?

Tags: stripe-payments

I use **Stripe** in a React app, in production I have the declineCode : "`insufficient_funds`", i would like simulate this when i use the **terminal** payment with the physical card.

In this documentation, wee can use decimal to produce specific responses, but nothing about "`insufficient_funds`" :
https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/references/testing

Do you know how i can do it please

Comment: While the error exists as per this: https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment?terminal-sdk-platform=server-driven#payment-failures I don't believe there are any test tokens to replicate it: https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/references/testing#physical-test-cards This isn't unique to Terminal, there are other scenarios which don't have a dedicated test token.

Comment: It's a harm because it was a production error only via the terminal, other methods work correctly